# How rare are unholey permutations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, permutations, symmetric-groups, random-permutations

For $S\subset [n]:=\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$, define $\delta(S)$ to be the number of $m\in S$ such that $m+1\notin S$.

Given a permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$, we define the *holeyness* $D(\pi)$ of $\pi$ as being $$\max_{S\subset [n]} (\delta(\pi(S))-\delta(S)).$$
It is clear that $D(\pi)\geq 0$.

What is (roughly or exactly) the number of permutations $\pi$ of $[n]$ such that $D(\pi)\leq k$? What if you restrict $\pi$ to be an $n$-cycle?

Comment: The permutations with $D(\pi) = 0$ are the identity permutation and the reverse permutation. The number of permutations with $D(\pi) = 1$ starts $0,0,4,22,82,240,520,960,1590, 2442$ (from $n=1$ to $n=10$) and is not in OEIS.

Comment: If k is fixed, then one can construct a permutation pattern which must be avoided in order to have D(pi)<=k. Therefore the number of such permutations is at most exponential in n.

Comment: Yes, and a bound of the form $n^{O(k)} k^{O(n)}$ shouldn't be hard. I am guessing that a much better bound should be true, though - perhaps $C^n n^{O(k)}$.

Comment: see also https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001469

Comment: What if we redefine $\delta(S)$ to be the number of $m\in S$ such that $\sigma(m)\notin S$, where $\sigma = (1 2 \dotsc n)$? Is the number of permutations with $D(\pi)=1$ then in OEIS (as $n$ ranges over the positive integers)?

Comment: I was sorry to see the first question title go, though I recognise the new title is more informative...

Comment: Restored (as well as I can remember it).

Comment: The answer to the question in your comment is still no. $0, 0, 0, 16, 110, 492, 1680, 4160, 8640, \ldots$.

Comment: Do you really intend that $\delta$ ignores the absence of $1$?

Comment: Well, I think the new definition of $\delta$ is more natural. Are you proposing an alternative definition that gives rise to a sequence in OEIS, say?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a long comment.
I computed $P_{n}(q)=\sum_{\pi \in S_n} q^{D(\pi)}$,
and got the following polynomials:
\begin{array}{l}
 1 \\
 2 \\
 4 q+2 \\
 22 q+2 \\
 36 q^2+82 q+2 \\
 478 q^2+240 q+2 \\
 576 q^3+3942 q^2+520 q+2 \\
 14840 q^3+24518 q^2+960 q+2 \\
\end{array}
It seems that for odd $n$, $P_{n}(q)$ has degree $d=(n-1)/2$,
and the leading coefficient is $((d+1)!)^2$.

Similarly, $\sum_{\pi \in S_n, type(pi)=(n)} q^{D(\pi)}$ gave me
\begin{array}{l}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 2 q \\
 6 q \\
 8 q^2+16 q \\
 85 q^2+35 q \\
 96 q^3+564 q^2+60 q \\
 1978 q^3+2982 q^2+80 q \\
\end{array}

Also, it seems like both families of polynomials (checked for up to $n=8$),
are real-rooted.

One can also consider a cyclic version of holeyness,
where we add $1$ to $\delta(S)$ if not both $1$ and $n$ are in $S$.
Here, $n$ is the number of elements in the permutation.
What happens is that $D(\pi) = D( w\pi w^{-1})$ if $w = (123\dotsc,n)$,
so every polynomial is divisible by $n$.
\begin{array}{l}
 1 \\
 2 \\
 6 \\
 16 q+8 \\
 110 q+10 \\
 216 q^2+492 q+12 \\
 3346 q^2+1680 q+14 \\
 4608 q^3+31536 q^2+4160 q+16 \\
\end{array}
These also seem real-rooted.

Comment: I confirm the first table. The next two rows are $2 + 1590q + 112874q^2 + 234014q^3 + 14400q^4$ and $2 + 2442q + 388126q^2 + 2622844q^3 + 615386q^4$.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am very mistaken, there is an easy way to establish a bound of the
"much better" kind mentioned in the comments above. (I don't doubt one can and should give a more precise answer.)

Write $\phi$ for $\pi \sigma \pi^{-1}$
(meaning $\pi^{-1}\circ \sigma \circ \pi$),
where $\sigma = (1 2 \dotsc n)$. Then
$\delta(\pi(S))$ is the number of $m\in S$ such that $\phi(m) \notin S$.

(Well, there could be a difference of $1$, which does not matter. Let us redefine $\delta(S)$ to be the number of $m\in S$ such that $\sigma(m)\notin S$. Perhaps we should consult OEIS again, after this redefinition?)

For the sake of simplicity, we shall restrict our attention to maps $\pi$
without fixed points; that implies $\phi$ has no fixed points either.
(This case covers the case of $\pi$ ranging over $n$-cycles, in particular.)
Let $v=v_\phi$ be the number of $m\in [n]$ such that
$\phi(m) \notin \{\sigma(m), \sigma^{-1}(m)\}$.
A bit of doodling shows that
the number $w=w_\phi$ of consecutive pairs $A=\{m,\sigma(m)\}$ such that
$\phi(A)\cap A=\emptyset$ (called them "valid" pairs) is $\geq v_\phi/2$.

Now we build a set $S$ as follows. At each step, we add to $S$ a valid pair
$\{m,\sigma(m)\}$ that has not yet been marked as forbidden. We also
mark eight pairs as forbidden:
$$\{\phi(m),\sigma^{\pm 1}(\phi(m))\},
\{\phi(\sigma(m)),\sigma^{\pm 1}(\phi(\sigma(m)))\},
\{\phi^{-1}(m),\sigma^{\pm 1}(\phi^{-1}(m))\},
\{\phi^{-1}(\sigma(m)),\sigma^{\pm 1}(\phi^{-1}(\sigma(m)))\}.$$
In this way, we get to build a set $S$ of size at least
$2 \cdot w_\phi/9 \geq v_\phi/9$ with $\delta(S)\leq |S|/2$ and
$\phi(S)\cap S = \emptyset$, so that $\delta(\pi(S)) = |S|$.
Hence
$$D(\pi) \geq v_\phi/18.$$

Thus, the number of distinct $\phi$ without fixed points
coming from permutations $\pi$ with $D(\pi)\leq k$ is at most
$2^n n^{18 k}$ (in fact, at most $2^{n-18k} n^{18 k}$). Now,
at most $n$ permutations $\pi$ (in fact, exactly $n$ permutations $\pi$) give
rise to the same $\phi = \pi \sigma \pi^{-1}$. Therefore, the total number
of permutations without fixed points
$\pi$ of $[n]$ such that $D(\pi)\leq k$ is at most
$$2^n n^{18 k + 1}.$$

I think (though I haven't checked yet) that the analysis for arbitrary
permutations $\pi$ should require only a little more work.

Comment: ... and, of course if we do*not* redefine $\delta$, the above argument still yields an upper bound of $2^n n^{18k+37}$.